# Can't run NOCHECK CONSTRAINT on mysql - SQL syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql, database, constraints, sql-insert

I've create a table called `Students`.
It has 4 fields: Name, Age, Class, Years.

[image]

```
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Name  | varchar(50) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Age   | smallint    | YES  |     | 18      |       |
| Class | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Years | smallint    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I have added a CHECK CONSTRAINT on `Years` field that means that the value in `Years` column can't be lower than `3`.
I did it by

```
mysql> alter table Students
    -> add constraint CK_Years check (Years >= 3);
```

My goal here is to insert a query with a record which has a `Years` value of 2, which means it won't pass the `CK_Years` check constraint.

**I want to do it without changing the constraint or the fields in the insert statement.**
Is it possible?

```
mysql> insert into Students
    -> (Name, Age, Class, Years) values ("Eric","25","110","2");
```

I have tried:

```
mysql> alter table Students
    -> NOCHECK CONSTRAINT CK_Years;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOCHECK CONSTRAINT CK_Years' at line 2
```

I want to disable it just for this insert, and then bring it back (the check constraint).

As you can see, I got this error.
I tried to write it in couple ways. Wit `'CK_Years'` or `CK_Years` or

```
`CK_Years`
```

got the same error for all of these ways.

I have verified that I have the constraint in the table:

```
mysql> select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
    -> where table_name='Students';
+--------------------+-------------------+-----------------+--------------+------------+-----------------+----------+
| CONSTRAINT_CATALOG | CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA | CONSTRAINT_NAME | TABLE_SCHEMA | TABLE_NAME | CONSTRAINT_TYPE | ENFORCED |
+--------------------+-------------------+-----------------+--------------+------------+-----------------+----------+
| def                | School          | PRIMARY         | School     | Students   | PRIMARY KEY     | YES      |
| def                | School          | CK_Years        | School     | Students   | CHECK           | YES      |
+--------------------+-------------------+-----------------+--------------+------------+-----------------+----------+
```

So how can I do it without changing the constraint or the fields in the insert statement?
How can I fix the syntax error?
And what is the reason for it?

Thanks.

Comment: you can't disable it, so why do you have a >=3 constraint when you want to add 2 to it?

Comment: @nbk for practice. i'm studying SQL rn and I want to see if thats possible to bypass a constraint and temporary disable the constraint.

Comment: you can only disable foreign keys and key checks nothing more

Comment: NOCHECK is not supported by MySQL. It is available in T-SQL on MS SQL Server.

Comment: @nbk yes, and here I want to disable a key check, right? `CK_Years` is a key check, or at least I think so. (correct me if i'm wrong)

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular Ok, thank you. So what do you suggest here?

Comment: first i don't see ack_grades and a key is an index no check constarint

Comment: @nbk sorry, I meant `CK_Years` which defined as `CONSTRAINT_TYPE: CHECK`.
So bottom line, there is no way to do what i asked? Insert it without changing the constraint or the fields in the insert statement?

Comment: Even if it's possible, why would you do that? Database constraints ensure a minimum level of quality in your data. If you disable them, you'll be losing data quality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL does support syntax to alter a check constraint so it is not enforced, but it's different from the Microsoft SQL Server syntax.

```
mysql> alter table students alter check CK_Years NOT ENFORCED;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> insert into students values ('Eric',25,'110',2);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
```

It's documented here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html

If you re-enable it, the constraint is enforced, and if you had inserted any rows that violate the constraint, you get an error trying to re-enable it.

```
mysql> alter table students alter check CK_Years ENFORCED;
ERROR 3819 (HY000): Check constraint 'CK_Years' is violated.
```

Also once you make the constraint not enforced, it would take effect for all clients, not just for one INSERT.

So I don't think you can do what you intend with a CHECK constraint. You may have to write a trigger that enforces a similar condition on that column, but has logic to enforce it conditionally.

Or do what most developers did before MySQL supported CHECK constraints: enforce it in the client app, before doing the INSERT. Then you can apply any conditions you want.

Comment: Yeah, but I still don't see the point of even allowing this in normal circumstances. Maybe for maintenance purposes, while the db is down, or to insert millions of rows in a jiffy, idk.

Comment: I'd guess if you need to INSERT some data (doesn't matter if it's one row or many rows) that don't immediately conform to the CHECK constraint, but you plan to UPDATE the rows to valid values that satisfy the constraint before you re-enable it.

Comment: @TheImpaler: 
Here's an article that describes the use of NOCHECK in Microsoft SQL Server: https://database.guide/what-you-should-know-about-with-nocheck-when-enabling-a-check-constraint-in-sql-server/ You may find a scenario where you must load data, even though they don't satisfy the constraints. As you commented, this fails to support data integrity, but we've all experienced situations where we must choose between satisfying our academic pride versus satisfying the boss, or the client who is paying the bills.

Comment: "...who is paying the bills." -- point taken.